# URL regex in django with limited set of words

Tags: regex, django, url

Given the following django URL conf. entry:

```
url(r'^(?P<obj_ctype_name>\w+)/(?P<obj_id>\d+)/$',
    views.obj_view,
    name='obj_view')
```

How would I rewrite the parameter `(?P<obj_ctype_name>\w+)` to enforce that
it may only be one of "foo" "bar" or "baz" and still keep it as a named
parameter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`(?P<obj_ctype_name>foo|bar|baz)`