# URL pattern in django to match limited set of words

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

I have a URL pattern in Django where there is a variable (called `name`) that should only take one of a select list of words. Something like this:

```
path("profile/<marta|jose|felipe|manuela:name>/", views.profile),
```

So basically only these paths are valid:

- profile/marta/
- profile/jose/
- profile/felipe/
- profile/manuela/

How exactly can I configure this in the Django url patterns? The above syntax tries to illustrate the idea but doesn't work. I've seen [this ten year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996305/url-regex-in-django-with-limited-set-of-words) but that uses the previous format in the url patterns file so I imagine it should be done differently now...?

Comment: You could create a [custom path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) that matches those names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put them in view?

```
from django.http import Http404

def profiles(request, name):
    if not name in ['marta', 'jose', 'felipe', 'manuela']:
        raise Http404('You shall not pass!')
```

**Or** you can simply use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path):

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^profile/(?P<name>marta|jose|felipe|manuela)/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```